# Can mAP score be used to describe "recall" rate of a model?

Tags: object-detection

I have a general question regarding the `mAP` score used in measuring object detection system performance.

I understood how the `AP` score is calculated, by averaging precision over recall 0 to 1. And then we can compute `mAP`, by averaging `AP` score of different labels.

However, what I have been really confused, is that, it seems that `mAP` score is used to denote the "precision" of a model. Then what about the "recall" aspect? Note that generally speaking, when measuring the performance of a machine learning model, we need to report `precision` and `recall` at the same time, right? It seems that `mAP` can only cover the `precision` aspect of a model.

Am I missed anything here? Or `mAP` score, despite its name is derived from `Precision`, can indeed subsume both "precision" and "recall" and therefore become comprehensive enough?

Comment: average precision is relative to recall, its says something about the precision recall give/take.

Comment: @mshlis. Thanks for the clarification. Yes, that's what I can think about.. But is there any more "formal" description/statement such that "mAP is derived from both precision or recall"?

Comment: Look at F score

Comment: @mshlis Yes, I understood the definition of F score, but what's the relation with mAP?

Comment: @mshlis OK, I think I found what I am looking for. What I can say is that "mAP derieves from both precision and recall values, by computing the area under the precision-recall curve for a given class." In that sense, yes, it surely subsumes both precision and recall values in a way.